# What happens if you put a 100 Ah battery on a 48 V, 1500 W motor?

Tags: power, batteries

I got a 48 V, 1500 W hub motor kit to put on my bike. I also bought a 48 V, 100 Ah battery that constantly releases 40 Ah.  How long will it last? How fast will the bike go? Is it safe to use?

Comment: A battery doesn't "release 40ah."  Current flows at the rate of 40A.  If the battery can do that for one hour, then it has a capacity of 40Ah.

Comment: Gear ratio, wheels diameter should be added to your question.

Comment: You also need to mention the battery chemistry. If you run a lead-acid battery as though it was LFP, you'll kill it in a few dozen cycles at best.

Comment: Most e-bikes use motors with a 250 W rating. 1500 W is likely to destroy the drive chain components and / or wheels unless they have been rated for that power. A crash could result in non-reversible injury or death.

Comment: In addition to the question if the rest of the mechanical components can survive a 1500W motor, is this even legal in your country? Many countries put power and speed limits so the bike could be classified as a moped or motorbike. Which means you may be riding an illegal moped/motorbike because those need mandatory insurances which you must pay, and they are taxed as vehicles, and you have to pay the fees to officially classify the device as moped/motorbike. It gets even worse if you don't have a license for driving a moped/motorbike and are riding a device classified as one.

Comment: Note that rated power of "electric devices" is output power. If your 48V battery is fine with 40 **A** current, that's 1.9 kWatts. 1.5 kW at the motor axle is about 2kW at the motor controller input. Good news is the battery is in the right ballpark. Bad news is it won't supply *that* level of power for more than about two hours before being deeply discharged.

Answer (score 4):

Your question can't be answered without more information on motor usage and detailed specifications of the battery.

What's below should, however, give you some idea of how the specifications and units hang together, for future questions and calculations.

Power is voltage times current, or P = V·I. From this: I = P/V. For your motor this becomes 1500/48 = 31.25 A. This is a *maximum* current; the motor won't pull this current constantly. It depends greatly on acceleration, speed, friction, slope, terrain, etc.

Batteries don't deliver Ah; Ah is a unit of *capacity*. The unit for current is the ampere (A). Also, batteries don't "constantly deliver" 40 A, they deliver whatever the motor pulls, up to the maximum the battery is capable of.

The battery's 100 Ah is specified at a certain current; pull a larger current than specified, and the battery's capacity will be smaller. At smaller currents, capacity will be larger. Without detailed specifications of the battery there is no telling what its capacity is for your specific usage.

*Assuming* that you run the motor at full power (1500 W, 31.25 A) constantly, and *assuming* the battery's capacity (100 Ah) is specified at a current of around 30 A, and *assuming* all of the 100 Ah is useable capacity, and *assuming* there are no other current-consuming things on your bike, the battery will last 100 Ah/31.25 A = 3 hours and 12 minutes.

None of these assumptions will hold in real life, though.

How fast the bike will go can't be answered from the information you give; it depends on many other things, gearing being one of them.